# How to apply to QWebEngineView setStyleSheet()?

Tags: python, css, qt, qt-designer, qwebengineview

I am unable to apply setStyleSheet to QWebEngineView. The QWebEngineView contains a map from folium. I tried to do it like this but without success:

```js
self.webView = QWebEngineView()
        self.webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
        self.webView.setStyleSheet(u'border: 1px'
                                   u'border-radius: 10px')
        self.webView.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.ui.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.webView)
```

```js
        self.webView.setStyleSheet("""QWebEngineView{
                                                     border: 1px'
                                                     border-radius: 10px
}""")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply a specific style to a QWebEngineView object, one approach is to create a helper widget and add the QWebEngineView inside it. Then, you can apply the desired style to the helper widget, which will also affect the QWebEngineView inside it.

To do this, you can create a new widget, such as a QWidget or a QFrame, and set its layout to a QVBoxLayout or QHBoxLayout. Then, you can add the QWebEngineView object to the layout using the addWidget() method. Finally, you can apply the desired style to the helper widget using the setStyleSheet() method.

Here's an example that demonstrates this approach:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
        self.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;border-radius: 25px;background-color:red;")

    def initUI(self):

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        url = QUrl.fromUserInput("https://www.google.com")

        self.webEngineView = QWebEngineView()

        vbox.addWidget(self.webEngineView)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('QWebEngineView')
        self.webEngineView.load(url)
        self.show()



def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**This will be the result:**

[image]

Comment: I have it in a frame, I use setStyleSheet to change the frame, smoothing its corners by 10px. But when I push a QWebEngineView into it, the colored borders remain, but the edges of the QWebEngineView go beyond the rounded edges of the frame. I've added a picture.

Comment: `self.horizontalLayout_0 = QHBoxLayout(self.ui.map_frame)`
        `self.webView = QWebEngineView()`
        `self.webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())`
        `self.webView.setAutoFillBackground(False)`
        `self.horizontalLayout_0.addWidget(self.webView)`

If I understand you correctly, but in this case, the map will fail

Comment: from your picture, your stylesheet needs some `margin`, it is another issue, to  apply a specific style to a QWebEngineView you need a helper widget, this is so important

Comment: @Alejandro for using map qt has qtlocation classes why do you use QWebEngineView?

Comment: Because I use folium and how I found out it is inserted into QWebEngineView because of the html code.

Comment: @Alejandro To ensure a visually appealing layout, it is recommended to create some `margin` between the rectangular QWebEngineView object and the surrounding frame. This can be achieved by adjusting the positioning of the view within the frame. It is important to note that the size of the QWebEngineView window cannot be fixed, as it will depend on the content being displayed within it, and always will be Rectangle.